# Temporal Logic - Until

Tags: lo.logic, model-checking, temporal-logic

I have a doubt, in *Linear Temporal Logic LTL*, does the **Until operator** require that the first occurrence is the first term of the formula?

ex:  `a U b` does require that the first term is `a` ?
Is the sequence `bbbbbb..bb` valid?

Comment: I am not sure whether this is a research-level question in theoretical computer science.

Comment: Is not LTL a theoretical computer science topic?

Comment: Sure it is, but the question is quite basic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you evaulate until formulae on paths, you usually require that **either** $b$ is the case to begin with, **or** you have a number $a$'s until a $b$ is met.

$bbbb \ldots b$ therefore satisfies the formula.

**Example usage:**

If you want in a system to reach a state satisfying a **goal** property while ensuring that no intermediate states have a **bad** property you could verify the following formula:

$\lnot \text{bad } U \text{ goal }$

One way to satisfy this property is that the starting configuration satisfies the desired property i.e **goal** (the semantics may also require $\lnot$bad in this configuration)